# Does sufficient smoothness of a function have any relation to its geometrical character?

Tags: calculus

**A function is sufficiently smooth if it is differentiable sufficient number of times.**

Is the word "smooth" introduced only because the surface or the curve given by this type of function would be physically smooth ?

> By "physically smooth" I mean feel of smoothness by hand.

Comment: This is vague, because "physically smooth" is hard to precisely define. But in my opinion, if a function is $C^1$ it is "physically" smooth.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be smooth it (and its differentials) needs to be differentiable and continuous.  Because the differential has to be continuous the line can't have sharp cusps.  So the curve can be "bumpy" but not "pointy".

Depending on what you perceive as physical smoothness these objects would be smooth, though there is nothing stopping a "smooth" curve from having many tiny bumps that would be felt as roughness.